# Lost on how to make setFormula on calling cell work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

This is my apps script function which is essentially trying to reverse sheets' `FORMULATEXT`:

```js
function textFormula(formula) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  cell.setFormula(formula);
}
```

This is how I'm calling it in a cell in Sheets:
[image]

And this is the error I'm getting:
[image]

From what I gathered, I should be able to use my custom function to affect the calling cell? Idk, lost.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: @doubleunary Yes, maybe. X = taking a formula and replacing all the cell references with a different column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a custom function can change the values in the spreadsheet is by **returning** values. You cannot use any of the various `.set` methods in a custom function, and thus cannot modify formulas.